# Dictionary get item with highest value and key

Tags: c#, dictionary

In my dictionary(int,int) I'm trying to get the key where the value is 3 and the key is the biggest.
If I want to get the key where the value is 3 I can use this code:

```
var max = double_list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 3).Key;
```

But if my dictionary contains multiple items where the value is 3 I get the first item (see "FirstOrDefault") with 3, what I actually want is when there is more than one item with value 3 I want to compare the items by their key and get the item with the highest key.

### For example:

### | Key | Value

### | 12 | 3

### |  13  |  2

### |  18  |  3

I want to get 18 as result, not 12. I hope you can understand what my problem is. Sorry for my bad english, any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: var max = double_list.Where(x => x.Value == 3 && x.Key == double_list.Max(item =? item.Key));

Answer (score 11):

The simplest approach is just to use [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max):

```
var max = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == 3).Max(x => x.Key);
```

If you want to get more than just the highest key, you'd use something like:

```
var topTwo = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == 3)
                       .Select(x => x.Key)
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                       .Take(2);
```

But I'd definitely use `Max` if you just want the highest single key.

Comment: It works in this case, but what if I also want to get the second best item. Let's say my dictionary has 10 items, 3 items have the value 3, now I want to get the two items with the highest key out of the 3 items. Do you hvae any general code for that purpose?

Comment: @user3868224: In that case, you'd use `Select`, `OrderByDescending` and `Take`. But that's a different question... I'll edit this into the answer, but please in future ask what you really want rather than just an overly simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert `OrderByDescending` in your query:

```
var max = double_list
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value == 3)
  .FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Comment: There's no need to use a full ordering; we only need the maximum value. Additionally, you're now ordering by a boolean, with nothing to do with the key...

Comment: Good point.  Order was what sprang to mind, but using Max is a better solution.